# Numbers formed by the concatenation of two consecutive Mersenne numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

The ec numbers are so defined:

$ec(n)=(2^{n}-1)*10^d+2^{n-1}-1$, where $d$ is the number of decimal digits of $2^{n-1}-1$.
In other words, ec(n) is obtained by the concatenation of two consecutive Mersenne numbers, $40952047$ for example.
Using Pari, I found the following values of $n$ for which $ec(n)$ $\equiv 1666667 \pmod {666667}$:
$n=18,19,20,17094,34188,51282,68376,85196,85197,85198,205128,222222,239316,255551,255552.255553...$

As you can see, periodically,three consecutive $ec(n)'s$ pop up which are congruent to $1666667$ $\pmod{666667}$: $ec(18),ec(19),ec(20)$ the first triple, then $ec(85196),ec(85197),ec(85198)$, then $ec(255551),ec(255552),ec(255553)$...
What is the periodicity of these triples?

Answer (score 2):

The congruence $ec(n)\equiv 1666667 \pmod{666667}$ is equivalent to
$$10^{d(n)}\equiv -\frac{1}{2}\pmod{666667}$$
where $d(n)$ denotes the number of digits in $2^{n-1}-1$. Let's denote by $A$ the set of all $n$ for which $d(n)$ satisfies this congruence, and denote by $B$ the set of $n$ which satisfy $$d(n)=d(n+1)=d(n+2)$$
or in other words $n\in B$ iff $2^{n-1},2^n,2^{n+1}$ all have the same number of digits. It is easy to show that the sets $A,B$ are infinite, and your "special triples" correspond to the intersection $A\cap B$.

At least heuristically it is easy to see that this intersection is infinite, since $d(A)$ is an arithmetic progression, whereas $d(B)$ is given by an "irrational condition", i.e. all numbers $d$ for which
$$\left\lfloor\frac{d-1}{\log_{10} 2}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{d-2}{\log_{10}2}\right\rfloor=2$$
For example the first element in $d(A)\cap d(B)$ is $d=6$, and $d^{-1}(6)$ is $\{18,19,20\}$.

Comment: can you proof that the intersection is infinite?

Comment: @EnzoCreti yes, you can make the proof rigorous with standard techniques. If the intersection was finite, then fractional part of $\frac{d}{\log_{10} 2}$ would avoid a positive length subinterval of $[0,1]$. You can show that this is not the case using the pigeonhole principle and the irrationality of $\log 2$.